# pass images on a board

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, image

[image: mydatabase board]

Hello ,I have create this database in the image.On **b_color** (I have black or red).On **piece_color**(red and black). On **piece** I have pawn1 (P1) and pawn2(P2).
All that on mysql.
On my index page I have create 2 raws and 12 columns,so it will be 24 boxes.I have created that with this code.

```
$(function () {
    draw_empty_board();
    fill_board();
    $('#do_move').click(do_move);
    $('#chess_reset').click(do_reset);
});


function draw_empty_board() {
    var t='<table id="chess_table">';
    for(var i=2;i>0;i--) {
        
        t += '<tr>';
        t += '<td class="line_label">'+i+'</td>';
        for(var j=1;j<13;j++) {
            
        
            t += '<td class="chess_square" id="square_'+j+'_'+i+'">' + j +','+i+'</td>'; 
            
        }
        t+='</tr>';
    }
    t += '<tr><td class="column_label line_label"></td>';
    for(var j=1;j<13;j++) {
        
        t += '<td class="column_label">'+j+'</td>';
    }
    t+='</tr>';
    t+='</table>';
    
    $('#chess_board').html(t);
}

function fill_board() {
    $.ajax({url: "chess.php/board/", success: fill_board_by_data });
    
}

function fill_board_by_data(data) {
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        var o = data[i];
        var id = '#square_'+ o.x +'_' + o.y;
        var c = (o.piece!=null)?o.piece_color + o.piece:'';
        var im = (o.piece!=null)?'<img class="piece" src="images/'+c+'.png">':'';
        var im = c;
        $(id).addClass(o.b_color+'_square').html(im);
        
    }
```

The code is running [image].I want to fill this board with two images.
I have created a folder named images,so I will take the pictures and fill my board with those two images.
https://p7.hiclipart.com/preview/143/606/545/clip-art-bullet-thumbnail.jpg for black
https://www.clker.com/cliparts/d/5/T/A/K/2/red-circle-hi.png        for red .
I have save those fotos in png and there are inside of images folder.
The problem is I think with my database..

Comment: It's like I understood your issue... but at the end you said you think the problem is with your database ! Do you mean, you are finding a difficulty to project those pawns from database using Ajax? Please clarify what's missing here.. ! would you mind share a sample code of your data ?

Comment: I already solved your problem using jQuery... I'll be back tomorrow and I expect a static sample of data and a better explanation to what's missing here ? :)

Comment: yes I was too tired and I thought I have the problem with my database...The sentence I say "The problem is I think with my database.." ,forget it.

Comment: @Bilel I want in [1,1] to have the blacks ,16 images from black .In position [12,2 ] I  want to have  16 from red

Comment: You confused me again with the number 16 ! :) Ok can you explain the objective of your code? or send a sample static Data? In meantime, you check using the console the response of the ajax call... may be that's your problem. It's also Possible that you have a contentType issue.

Comment: @Bilel  with 16 I mean  the  https://www.clker.com/cliparts/d/5/T/A/K/2/red-circle-hi.png  (those  are the pawns) I want those to put in 12,2. and another 16  for those https://p7.hiclipart.com/preview/143/606/545/clip-art-bullet-thumbnail.jpg . to put those in possition as you see it in the orange image in position12,2.Hope you understand me now where I stuck :D

Comment: I'm posting a sample... and I'm still not sure about the goal here :) 16 times the same picture in a cell, 16 other different pictures in this cell... So ignored the 16 ! Anyway, I imagined a sample json data that could fit to your code and I hope it could be helpful.

Comment: @Bilel thanks a lot of man :) I am trying to create a game.If you could do with somehow I to add 16 times the same image on the same box,I would be greatful ! :)

Comment: I'm sure it's not a chess game (usual chessboard is 8x8) :) How do you expect those 16 pieces to appear ? Like one near the other , or 4 lines of 4 pieces  in a  large cell? Because I see in your code, you are expecting to move them, so they should be easily clickable and uniquely identified to keep track of the moves I guess..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this code could be helpful to you... I also suggested using Css (dots) as an alternative to pictures.

```js
  //Because I can't rename hosted images filenames
  //I'm using this color dictionary
  let colors={black:"https://i.imgur.com/dL3J8XS.jpeg",red:'https://i.imgur.com/ZEZLSOo.png'}
  //
  
  let items = [
  {
    "x": 1,
    "y": 1,
    "piece":"p",
    "piece_color": "black",
    "b_color": "black"
  },
  {
    "x": 12,
    "y": 2,
    "piece":"p",
    "piece_color": "red",
    "b_color": "red"
  }
  ];
  $(function () {
    draw_empty_board();
    fill_board();
    //$('#do_move').click(do_move);
    //$('#chess_reset').click(do_reset);
});

  function draw_empty_board() {
    var t='<table id="chess_table">';
    for(var i=2;i>0;i--) {
        
        t += '<tr>';
        t += '<td class="line_label">'+i+'</td>';
        for(var j=1;j<13;j++) {
            
        
            t += '<td class="chess_square" id="square_'+j+'_'+i+'"></td>'; 
            
        }
        t+='</tr>';
    }
    t += '<tr><td class="column_label line_label"></td>';
    for(var j=1;j<13;j++) {
        
        t += '<td class="column_label">'+j+'</td>';
    }
    t+='</tr>';
    t+='</table>';
    
    $('#chess_board').html(t);
}
function fill_board() {
    //$.ajax({url: "chess.php/board/", success: fill_board_by_data });
    //I'm a calling static data here
    fill_board_by_data(items);
    
}

function fill_board_by_data(data) {
    
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {

        var o = data[i];
        var id = '#square_'+ o.x +'_' + o.y;
        //var c = (o.piece!=null)?o.piece_color + o.piece:'';
        var c = (o.piece!=null)?o.piece_color:'';
        
        //$(id).append('<span class="'+c+'dot"></span>');
        var im = (o.piece!=null)?'<img class="piece" src="'+colors[c]+'.png">':'';
        $(id).addClass(o.b_color+'_square').html(im);
        
    }
}
```

```css
  table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border:2px solid;
  }
  td{
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    border:1px solid;
  }
  
  /*this is a suggested Css alternative to images */
.reddot {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
    .blackdot {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
img{width:25px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chess_board"></div>
```